# Get value from xml file or link in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have xml file, and i need to get value  from id="45" in PHP. How I can do this? In the future, i need to get value from link, which gives xml. I never worked with xml. PHP version 5.3.29

```
<ValCurs Date="27/10/2014" Version="1.1">
    <Valute id="1">
        <NumCode>036</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>100</Nominal>
        <Name>австралійських доларів</Name>
        <Value>1138.7859</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute id="45">
        <NumCode>944</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
        <Nominal>100</Nominal>
        <Name>азербайджанських манатів</Name>
        <Value>1651.2100</Value>
    </Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
$xml = '
<ValCurs Date="27/10/2014" Version="1.1">
    <Valute id="1">
        <NumCode>036</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>100</Nominal>
        <Name>?????????????? ???????</Name>
        <Value>1138.7859</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute id="45">
        <NumCode>944</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
        <Nominal>100</Nominal>
        <Name>???????????????? ???????</Name>
        <Value>1651.2100</Value>
    </Valute>
</ValCurs>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

$result = $xml->xpath( "//Valute[@id='45']" );

if ( $result ) {
    foreach( $result as $node ) {
        echo $node->Value; // output: 1651.2100
    }
}
```

More info:

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)
[xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)